# Executing VaultQuery

Tags: corda

total beginner here.

I have a State with these values:

```
private final Party issuer;
private final Party owner;
private final int patient;
private final String hash;
```

I want to run a vaultQuery where it will return the transactions where the patient is a specific ID. For example, if the patient ID is 16038382, and I have initiated several flows that contained that ID and several flows that have different patient IDs, I only want to run the vaultQuery to contain transactions where the patient ID is 16038382.

How do I do this? I have read the Vault Query API and it just did not make sense to me. Do I have to set up another flow to get the data I need? What do I need to enter in the shell where I am executing the nodes from? I would really appreciate some answers and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If this is just for development purpose, and you just want to take a look at your vault as you go. 
I would suggest take a look our latest vscode extension where we implemented an UI for looking into vault. 
Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=R3.vscode-corda

If you are new to Corda, feel free to join our public slack @slack.corda.net

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a `persistentState` like example `persistentPatientState` and use some code like this:

```
val generalCriteria = VaultQueryCriteria(Vault.StateStatus.ALL)

val results = builder {
    val patientIndex = PersistentPatientState::patient.equal(12345)

    val customCriteria1 = VaultCustomQueryCriteria(patientIndex)

    val criteria = generalCriteria.and(customCriteria1)
    vaultService.queryBy<Patient.State>(criteria)
}
```